# how we can see all running services Linux machine?

Tags: linux, service, command, devops

I have a Linux [ Ubuntu Version 16.04 or Upper version ] machine and I want to see how many services are running right now and how many services are installed using 1 command or the minimum commands of use. How can I see this?

Answer (score 44):

## List services

### service

The `service --status-all` command will list all services on your Ubuntu Server (both running services and not running services):

```
service --status-all
```

Using the `grep` command, we can filter the output to show only the running services:

```
service --status-all | grep '\[ + \]'
```

To list Ubuntu services that are not running, type:

```
service --status-all | grep '\[ - \]'
```

The `service` command can be used to list services in all Ubuntu releases, including Ubuntu 17, 16.04, and 14.04.

### systemctl

To list all running services on Ubuntu, Type:

```
systemctl list-units
```

## Count

### running services

```
service --status-all | grep -c '\[ + \]'
```

### not running services

```
service --status-all | grep -c '\[ - \]'
```

### all services

```
service --status-all | grep -c ''
```

Comment: Please click the Linux tag and read what it says.

Comment: Dear arturwwl, 
Thank you for replay and help.

Answer (score 6):

Although *service* is still working on ubuntu 22, it is recommended to use *systemctl* for list running services as follows:

```
sudo systemctl list-units --state running
```